# Game crashes unity Google Play Services

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

For some reason my game crashes on android everytime its loaded it works fine in the unity editor but when building apk and releasing to app store it crashes

I know for a fact that the issue is due to Google Play Services because if i comment out all the google play code the game works

So I checked my crash logs in the console and this is what I see

```html
backtrace:
  native: pc 0000000000039c24  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
  native: pc 0000000000016af5  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
  native: pc 0000000000017707  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
  native: pc 0000000000013f75  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
  native: pc 0000000000012a3c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
  native: pc 0000000000226033  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+170)
  native: pc 00000000000a72e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1360)
  native: pc 00000000000b1401  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1112)
  native: pc 00000000000b1945  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+68)
  native: pc 00000000001bdc1d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::RegisterNativeMethods(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, JNINativeMethod const*, int, bool)+1732)
  native: pc 00000000001bdda5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::RegisterNatives(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, JNINativeMethod const*, int)+12)
  native: pc 000000000009221b  /data/app/com.FlameForged.idleTD-1/lib/arm/libgpg.so
  native: pc 0000000000092e37  /data/app/com.FlameForged.idleTD-1/lib/arm/libgpg.so
  native: pc 00000000000933dd  /data/app/com.FlameForged.idleTD-1/lib/arm/libgpg.so
  native: pc 000000000008dc69  /data/app/com.FlameForged.idleTD-1/lib/arm/libgpg.so (gpg::AndroidPlatformConfiguration::Valid() const+76)
  native: pc 0000000000053441  /data/app/com.FlameForged.idleTD-1/lib/arm/libgpg.so (gpg::GameServices::Builder::Create(gpg::AndroidPlatformConfiguration const&)+40)
  native: pc 00000000000c73dd  /data/app/com.FlameForged.idleTD-1/lib/arm/libgpg.so (GameServices_Builder_Create+16)
  native: pc 000000000000c104  <unknown>
```

I honestly have no idea what this means and im not entirely sure what to do to fix the issue

To explain further I have a preloader scene that does some important loading before the game actually starts(everything is googd to this point) now when I load up the men scene(where my load function is called) the game immediatly crashes

If any code is needed to help fix the issue I am happy to provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a more descriptive exception message somewhere before this in the log.  It *might* be because you have a mismatch between the plugin and the play-services*.aar versions.   If you are using 0.9.36 or earlier of the plugin, you need to use 10.0.0 or earlier of play-services libraries.

Ideally, you can use the latest version of the plugin (0.9.38a) which requires play-services 10.2 or later.

If it still does not work, can you post more of the log?

Comment: actually fixed the issue it came from the unity update  theres an incompatibility issue apparently forcing the app to use 10.0.1 in the version class and then going to assets->google play->resolve jars fixes the issue